# Installing Directx and Direct3D in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, directx, direct3d

I have scoured the Internet for this but I cannot simply find the instructions.

I am trying to install DirectX and Direct3D in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. How do I install it? What do I need to download?

According to [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/07/01/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2013-edition.aspx), I think DirectX hasn't released for VS 2013. Am I wrong?

I am learning DirectX for the first time, so please forgive me if my questions seems very basic.

Comment: Which OS are you using, and which DirectX version will you be targeting?

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1 and I want to use DirectX 11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using at least Windows 7, you'll want to download the [Windows SDK for Windows 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx). It includes DirectX, and supports Visual Studio 2013.

Visual Studio 2013 may (depending on your install) include parts of the Windows SDK already, so you may want to make sure you don't already have DirectX headers/libraries installed.

Comment: Same goes for Windows 8.1?

Comment: @RohitShinde Yes, the SDK Supports Windows 7, 8 and 8.1.

Comment: Okay. And how do I make sure that I don't already have those headers you mentioned?

Comment: @RohitShinde I can check the installation path when I'm back at my Windows machine, from memory the SDKs are under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits`, there should be a folder under 8.1 containing what's already installed.